# Where does Exchange Server store log path configuration?

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2016

Does anyone know where Exchange Admin Center (EAC) store the configuration. I writting an application to collect Message Tracking Log configuration from Exchange Server. Thus, i need some programmable way to get Message Tracking Log Path from Exchange Server.

I configured Message Tracking Log Path on EAC gui. Then, I used ADSI and found the `mxExchMessageTrackingPath` attribute under `Configuration/Services/Exchange Server/<Organization Name>/Servers/<Exchange Server Name>/Transport Configuration/Mailbox` but it seem not being set. Other log path configurations are also not as the same as the value i configured on EAC gui.

Is there any way to get these settings from Exchange Server. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to get message tracking log path:

`Get-TransportService | Format-List MessageTrackingLog*`

[image]

For more details: [Configure message tracking in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/configure-message-tracking?view=exchserver-2019) and [Transport logs in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/transport-logs?view=exchserver-2019)

Comment: I tried to run the command under current user and it works fine. However, when the application run under System user. it returns error. Is it possble for system user to run the Exchange shell?

Comment: What is the error showing? Try to run powershell as administrator and check if this issue continues.